# unix sed and awk commands get records and display html table

Tags: html, bash, unix, sh

Am new to unix i tried to get users and their directory details using sed and awk commands and tried to display it in html table

I have tried the following code it can able to print one column of the table,I can't able to create 2nd and 3rd column kindly tell me the possible ways to print the records in the2nd and 3rd column

```
vars=`cat /etc/passwd | sed -e "s/:/\t/g" | awk '{print $1}'`
echo '<table style="width:100%" border="2px"><tr><th>username</th><th>column1</th><th>column2</th>' >> demo.html
for variable in $vars
 do
 echo "<tr><td>$variable</td></tr>" >> demo.html
done
 echo "</table>" >> demo.html
```

Comment: what do you expect to see as values for `column1` and `column2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will generate a table which looks like the image below :

```
 awk -F':' 'BEGIN{print "<table border=1    cellpadding=1  cellspacing=0    bordercolor=BLACK ><tr><td>User Name</td><td>Default Shell</td></tr>"}{ print "<tr><td>"$1"</td><td>"$(NF)"</td></tr>"} END { print "</table>" } ' /etc/passwd
```

#### Output

[image: table_sample]

Comment: Thank you so much it saved my time @Matias

Comment: @vimalkumar No problem buddy. thanks for the encouragement. :)

Comment: one more help Martias how can i print other fields like password,gid ,uid ,home directory

Comment: You need to add them here : { print "<tr><td>"$1"</td><td>"$(NF)"</td></tr>"}. Also on the BEGIN statement you can add headers as much as you want.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the only the first columns might contain whitespace and the 2nd and 3rd will not,
then here's one way to write such script:

```
{
echo '<table style="width:100%" border="2px"><tr><th>username</th><th>column1</th><th>column2</th>'
awk -F: '{print $1; print $2, $3}' /etc/passwd | while read user
do
    read pass uid
    echo "<tr><td>$user</td><td>$pass</td><td>$uid</td></tr>"
done
echo "</table>" 
} | tee demo.html
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one easy way using `awk`:

```
awk -F':' '
           function wrap(tag,x) {return "<"tag">"x"</"tag">"}
           function row(x)      {return wrap("tr",x)}
           function cell(x)     {return wrap("td",x)}

           BEGIN {
               print "<table style=\"width:100%\" border=\"2px\">"
               print row(cell("user_name")  cell("home_dir"))
           }
           {
               print row(cell($1) cell($6) )
           }
           END{
               print "</table>"
           }
          ' /etc/passwd
```

Would Output (with few records):

```html
<table style="width:100%" border="2px">
<tr><td>user_name</td><td>home_dir</td></tr>
<tr><td>root</td><td>/root</td></tr>
<tr><td>daemon</td><td>/usr/sbin</td></tr>
<tr><td>bin</td><td>/bin</td></tr>
<tr><td>sys</td><td>/dev</td></tr>
<tr><td>sync</td><td>/bin</td></tr>
<tr><td>akshay</td><td>/home/akshay</td></tr>
<tr><td>mysql</td><td>/nonexistent</td></tr>
<tr><td>gdm</td><td>/var/lib/gdm3</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Love the idea of making functions for the tags. Nice.